# I have many strange links in Google Search Console Report

Tags: google-search-console, crawl-errors

[image]

I'm pretty much new in this field!
Google console sent me the report and I see there:
1,006 not indexed pages

And when I checked why pages are not indexed
For example, I went to "Discovered-not indexed"

I saw many strange links.

What is this, and how bad it is for the website

[image]

Comment: What type of system are you using to create/run your website? (i.e. Wordpress, Drupal, Joomla...)

Answer (score 1):

As long as they are returning not found (404) codes, you are ok.

However, it would be best to check a few things to be on the safe side:

1. Check if those links are not being created by your own website. You can try a tool like **Screaming Frog**, **Ahrefs**' or **SEMrush**'s website audits to find out.
2. Verify that those links aren't present in your websites' **sitemap**.
3. Run a security scanner on your site. For example, if you are on Wordpress you can try **Bulletproof Security**, **Sucuri** or **Wordfence**.